# javascript for loop going in infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I made a simple timer in `javascript` using a for loop, but upon clicking the button to call the function test(), the whole page freezes up so I assume I have an infinite loop somewhere
This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function test() {
    var HowLong = 5;
    for (var i=0;i<HowLong;i--) {
      document.write(HowLong[i] + "<br>");
    }
  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Start Timer">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: simple logic, in the loop i never be > HowLong to break the condition, so infinite loop.

Comment: There a couple of problems: a) Yes you have an infinite loop, because you are not counting up. b) `HowLong` is a number, but you are trying to use it like an object (`HowLong[i]`). You probably want to use `i` only. c) Even if you fix that, you wouldn't actually see the change of each iteration. The execution of the loop is so instantaneous that you will only see the change of the last iteration. I recommend to read a tutorial about basic data types in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: @user3247345 : I have a wierd feeling that your totally wrong behind the logic for implementing a count-down timer..

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have infinite loop problem in the for loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<HowLong;i--)
```

Instead of `i--` try `i++`

```
for (var i=0;i<HowLong;i++)
```

One more thing `HowLong` is not an array so you can't use `HowLong[i]`, just simply use :

```
document.write(i+ "<br>");
```

As `@jfriend00` has mentioned in comments When you use `document.write()` after the document is loaded, it will clear the current document and start a new one. In your case your button `Start Timer` will be cleared. If you want to avoid it you can use `div` and add value to it.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function test() {
      var HowLong = 5;
      for(var i=0;i<HowLong;i++) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
      }
    } 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Start Timer">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's another issue too.  When you use `document.write()` after the document is loaded, it will clear the current document and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
for (var i=0;i<HowLong;i++) {
    document.write(i + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: It no longer lags, simply prints 'undefined' the amount of times as HowLong is

Comment: @user3247345: Because you are trying to access the properties `0`, `1`, `2`, etc of a **number** (`HowLong[i]`). Numbers don't have such properties, arrays usually do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var HowLong = 5;
  var isRun = false;

  function mf(i){
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = i;
  }
  function rt(i)
  {
        setTimeout(function(){
            mf(i++);
            if(i!=HowLong+1)rt(i);
            else isRun = false;
        }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1sec
  }
  function test() {
    var i = 1;
    if(!isRun)
    {
        isRun = true;
        rt(i);
    }
  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myAnchor"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Start Timer">
</body>
</html>
```

you forget to add delay in your loop